# Play html video when its in viewport, pause on leave viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I'm trying to play my video as soon as it's in the viewport and when it's not in the viewport anymore it's supposed to pause.

I've tried this so far:

HTML code:

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video><br>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#video:in-viewport").play();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#video:in-viewport").play();
});
```

I'm using this plugin for the in-viewport check

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

This is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hytpm3xe/2/

Does anyone have an idea how to get this working correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1) You want to refer to the tag, not the id, so no "#"…

```
$("video:in-viewport")
```

2) To use the video API, you have to use the DOM object, not jQuery object, so the final call would look something like…

```
$("video:in-viewport")[0].play();
```

Comment: Thanks that works but when i leave the viewport the video doesnt stop. Do you have any ideas how to pause the video when leaving the viewport?

Comment: I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it will work… $("video").not("video:in-viewport")[0].pause();

Comment: Code run but always showing error in consol  on every time doing scroll "Cannot read property 'play' of undefined" how to fix it

Comment: @Inderjeet can you make a jsfiddle or a codepen showing your issue?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed https://jsfiddle.net/ar2sb0zy/ . i have create js fiddle see consol showing error on every scroll.....Error showing :- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Comment: Your issue is ":in-viewport".  If the element isn't in the viewport, it's undefined.  You would need to do a test to see if it exists before telling it to play.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed you said right..I knew this thing even before you said but what is the solution for this. How to remove undefined error if video not "in viewport"..

Comment: Like I said, do a test to see if it exists before telling it to play.  https://jsfiddle.net/ar2sb0zy/1/